# Add NuGet Package to Private NuGet Feed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package in one private NuGet Feed. I want to include that NuGet package in a different private NuGet Feed. How do I add a package to NuGet from my local computer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the feed you want to add the package to. If it's an HTTP feed that supports the NuGet protocol, like nuget.org or an Azure Devops Artifacts feed, then you can use [`nuget.exe push`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push). Some HTTP feeds may have a web page you can use to upload the package to. If you have a local file feed (even if it's a network share, it's still operating system file IO), then you can use [`nuget add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-add), but `nuget push` may work as well.

Unless you give us more information about your private feed, we can only give you this generic advice.